# Is SNMP supported in Android?

Tags: android, snmp

I would like to know if SNMP is supported in Android(2.1)?
If it is not available, is it possible to port the snmp source for Android?(some pointers plz..)

If it is available, how can I test the presence of it in my device.

All pointers are welcomed.

Thanks,
Sen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a really old question, but I was doing exactly what you're asking. The short answer is no, by default, SNMP is not supported on android 2.1. Because it isn't available, what I wound up doing was grabbing snmp4j's source code, and sticking it in android and making my own library. There are libraries (snmp4android comes to mind) but I found that it lacked certain classes I needed and did not have the whole snmp4j.agent branch.

There are a few dependencies and a few libraries that android is missing but most of them pertain to the log4j class.

To remedy that, just convert/make the switch to something like slf4j, which is a small logging library that you can include with your application.

I hope that answers some of your initial questions, and I hope this is still relevant even if it is an old question.

Comment: Thanks, Otra. Could you please give me an overview of how you did thing to make snmp work on android? That will be really useful and thankful, if you are willing to share.

Comment: Honestly all I wound up doing was downloading the snmp4j source and converting all the logging (which I believe was the only thing causing me trouble) to slf4j. Logging might not work that well after the conversion but it wasn't that big of a concern for me, I'm still testing out all the functions but I was able to create an agent and a client on android just by doing that.

Comment: @Otra - Did you do any work with traps using the SNMP4J port to Android?  I did something similar, and requests/responses seem to work without a problem, but I get an EACCES violation when I try to start up an Snmp instance to listen for traps.

Answer (score 3):

SNMP4J 2.x can be directly used on Android without changing its sources. The logging can be set to a simple console logger by calling

```
  static {
    LogFactory.setLogFactory(new ConsoleLogFactory());
    ConsoleLogAdapter.setDebugEnabled(true);
  }
```

in your root activity. Of course, you can implement a Android Logging Adapter too and register it as shown above.